# PowerBi - Highlight Weekend Bars on bar chart

Tags: powerbi

I have a bar chart with dates as the x axis
[image]

I need to highlight the weekends with a different colour.
In my calendar table I have a true/false column for if a date is a weekend

[image]

But I can't find within the conditional formatting of the columns anywhere to be able to use this.
When I pick rules it only gives me *count of weekend* not just a classic conditional statement of if(Weekend=TRUE) -> make column blue

Help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I've changed the Type to be categorical instead of continuous and got this
[image]

Which is a lot uglier as I'm not sure how to have fewer labels and I've changed the data type to Text (from True/False) and I have "Don't Summarize" for data summarization but conditional still gives:

[image]

It still has a summarize of either first or last which I can't remove

---

SOLUTION.

I followed Jonathan's suggestion of splitting them out.
I created two new measures, one for total of work - weekends and another for the same as weekdays.

[image]

[image]

(I then modified my "Total Hours Worked" to just add these two values so I still had a total).

[image]

This then allowed me to have put in each as a separate value on my chart giving the result I wanted.

[image]

(I have renamed these for the sake of the graph but they're just - Total Weekday Hours worked)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see where you're coming from seeing this dataset.
But as this doesn't seem a out of the box option in PowerBI charting as-is, can I suggest you split this table based on the column generated for weekends, resulting in

- weekends false > table weekdays
- weekends true > table weekends

(This is done by referencing the PowerBI query and then simply filtering it)
As a last step, showing both tables in the same chart, thus having control over which color which column gets.

Maybe not the presttiest solution going forward, but solving your problem now probably? Love to hear!

Comment: Thanks. I don't know if I did exactly what you meant but it pushed me in the right direction. Have edited the post to show the solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for bool values Power BI won't allow you to do what you want.
If it's a calculated column, try changing the logic to say "yes" / "no", or "weekend" / "weekday". After that you'll be able to add the rule you want.

Alternatively, select Table view on the left hand side, select your column, and under Column tools in the ribbon you can change the Data type to Text. It'll have the same result.

Comment: Have updated the post. Still getting a formatting issue where it's trying to summarize by first or last.

Comment: In your latest screenshot it looks like you can specify free text in the rule, though. Keep the summarization as First, but add the rule as per my answer. I think that should work.